# Django using media (uploading files and adding them to templates)

Tags: python, django, templates, upload

I'm trying to learn how to upload files in Django and use them in templates.
My goal is to create post form with multiuplad field but im starting with simple things. Im trying to uplad single files and add link to those files in tempalate. Thats what i have done so far:

model:

```
class Adds(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=u"Autor postu", blank=True, null=True)
image = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/')


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"\%s" % self.image.name
```

I've added function get_absolute_url to get url with MEDIA_ROOT added. Its not working because MEDIA_ROOT path part is with "\" and the res is separated with "/". Thats first question how to make this function work properly.

I am adding links like this `<a href="{{plik.get_absolute_url}}">{{plik.get_absolute_url}}</a>`
but i read about url function so i tryed somethin like this `<a href="{{plik.image.url}}">{{plik.image.url}}</a>`but it returns url without MEDIA_ROOT part so only "upladed_to_name/file_name".

My MEDIA_ROOT in settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_env", "my_static", "media")
```

In shell i have somethin like this:

```
In [1]: from voiceManaging.models import Pracownik

In [2]: i=Pracownik.objects.get(pk=1)

In [3]: i.zdjecie.url
Out[3]: 'photos/mama_0SADn31.jpg'

In [4]: i.zdjecie.path
Out[4]: u'E:\\Django\\Projects\\KCKAPP\\static_env\\media\\photos\\mama_0SADn31.
jpg'
```

Comment: Can you add what you have `MEDIA_ROOT` defined as?

Comment: What media storage class are you using? If you're not sure, it'll be `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` in your settings.

Comment: I dont have this static in my settings. So my DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE should be the same as MEDIA_ROOT?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the default [FileSystemStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/storage/) class, providing you have defined a `MEDIA_URL` in your settings the storage class can build a URL for your uploaded files using that setting & the corresponding file name using the `.url` attribute.

So using your example;

```
class Adds(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='photos')
```

To illustrate the attributes & what they each do for the FieldField take a look at this;

```
>>> add = Adds.objects.get(author="Mark")
>>> add.image
<FileField: mark.jpg>
>>> car.photo.name
'photos/mark.jpg'
>>> add.image.path
'/media/photos/mark.jpg'
>>> add.image.url
'http://media.example.com/photos/mark.jpg'
```

So `MEDIA_URL` should be a URL where your web server is configured to serve the files stored in `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: ok but how to change those "\" chars into "/".  Documentation claims that ulr() should return url with MEDIA_ROOT. So i think that there should be any way to use this MEDIA_ROOT.

Comment: @Max I've simplified my answer for the default FileSystemStorage class which will play nicely with `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` to allow you to just do `add.image.url` to get the full URL for the image.